# Desktop.getDesktop().open is not functioning as expected in KDE Plasma

Tags: java, linux, desktop-application, kde-plasma

So the code i'm running is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Thread(()->{
            try
            {
                Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(Main.class.getResource("/blank.jpg").getPath()));
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("oopse");
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

every time it calls Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(filePath)); and filepath ends in .jpg, for some reason the file is opened in firefox instead of Gwenview.

I want this application to be cross platform, and opening files is a huge part of my application. I need it to respect user preferences for default opening programs. How do i code this so it's friendly to Windows, OsX, and Ubuntu both gnome and plasma?

[My KDE jpg prefrences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvfZV.png)

Here is a fully runnable example: https://github.com/CodingSorcerer/Desktop-Open-Test

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: `FireFox` is most likely your default program to open `jpg`.

Comment: @Sedrick i updated the post to include my kde preferences. Firefox is clearly not at the top.

Comment: @kleopatra
i have added a github link with a fully runnable example.

Comment: What does `xdg-open /path/to/image.jpg` do?

Comment: @VGR the xdg-open command opens the file in Gwenview

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly - it clearly states the reproducible example is __required__ to be in the question

Comment: @kleopatra A runnable version of the code is provided in the github link. Please read the refrenced question and act accordingly.

Comment: @VGR i am using Openjdk version 16

Comment: external code doesn't exist (by the rules of this site - because the focus is not on you but in future readers .. references tend to fade away, making this question and potential answers useless) .. so this question is not answerable because it doesn't provide a [mcve].

Comment: @kleopatra Thank you for finally being upfront with what's wrong with this post. throwing links in peoples face with little to no explanation is not very helpful.

i have added the code to the code block. is this more acceptable?

Comment: You could patch it with [`Desktop#setOpenFileHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#setOpenFileHandler(java.awt.desktop.OpenFilesHandler)). Also File and getResource should be a no-no, but so be it.

Comment: Hmm, i'm looking into it. Not sure how DesktopSetOpenFileHandler works too well, as how am i supposed to know what Desktop Environment your using. the more i look into this it seems like a KDE Plasma problem and not a problem with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I come back to this question much later and it turns out I found the solution. Java doesn't follow the same system preferences as the KDE desktop. To configure the default applications for the JVM in KDE plasma you need to open up terminal and edit `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

Doing this will change the system defaults for Java-based applications.

Under section

`[Default Applications]`

I've added the following line to get the desired result:

`image/jpg=org.kde.gwenview.desktop;`